# Extension Development : Redirect on error

Tags: add-on, extension, redirects, hook

I'm developing an extension that uses the `member_update_end` hook. This extension requires communicating with a 3rd party API, which I can't guarantee will always be active.

As a side note, the hook will be called when a specific custom member field is updated, which I do in my templates via `Freemember`.

Should this 3rd party API fail to respond with the output I want, how can I present (or redirect to?) an error message/template to the user? Is there an EE method (or best practice) for such things while inside an extension, that makes sure it won't interrupt anything else that needs to happen (like other hooks that may be set, etc.)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the hooked function you can return the error message which will be displayed as "User Message".

Like:

```
function function_name($member_id, $data)
{
$errors = array();
#####
Data processing with API

Put all the errors into the array $errors

#####

if( count ($errors) > 0 )
return $this->EE->output->show_user_error('general', $errors);
}
```

I hope, it would help you.